# How to embed a UIViewController's view into another view without breaking responder chain

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, xcode11, swift4.2

I'm trying to implement a base class for View Controllers that will add a top banner that is shown and hidden based on a specific status. Because my `UIViewController` extend this base class the `view` property is already loaded by the time I have to embed the original `view` property into a new `view` property that is created programmatically.

The embedding works fine (UI wise) the views adjust themselves appropriately however the issue that I'm seeing is that after embedding it the embedded views no longer respond to touch events, in the controller that I'm originally embedding I've got a table view with 16 rows and a button, before embedding it they both respond to tap and scroll events correctly.

I'm constrained to the fact that I cannot use a split view controller in IB to achieve the dual view split.

Here is my current implementation, can't seem to figure out what I'm missing to have event's propagate, I've tried using a custom view that overrides `hitTest()` to no avail for both `newRootView` and `contentView` variables.

Any help or insights are really appreciated, thanks!

```swift
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    var isInOfflineMode: Bool {
       didSet { if isInOfflineMode { embedControllerView() }}
    }

    var offlineBanner: UIView!
    var contentView: UIView!

    private func embedControllerView() {
        guard let currentRoot = viewIfLoaded else { return }

        currentRoot.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        let newRootView = UIView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        newRootView.backgroundColor = .yellow // debugging
        newRootView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        newRootView.clipsToBounds = true
        view = newRootView

        offlineBanner = createOfflineBanner() // returns a button that I've verified to be tapable.

        view.addSubview(offlineBanner)

        contentView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        contentView.backgroundColor = .cyan // debugging
        contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        view.addSubview(contentView)

        contentView.addSubview(currentRoot)

        let bannerHeight: CGFloat = 40.00
        var topAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor
        var bottomAnchor: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor
        var trailingAnchor: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor
        var leadingAnchor: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            topAnchor = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor
            bottomAnchor = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor
            leadingAnchor = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor
            trailingAnchor = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor
        } else {
            topAnchor = view.topAnchor
            bottomAnchor = view.bottomAnchor
            leadingAnchor = view.leadingAnchor
            trailingAnchor = view.trailingAnchor
        }

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            offlineBanner.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: bannerHeight),
            offlineBanner.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            offlineBanner.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            offlineBanner.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
        ])

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: bannerHeight),
            contentView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
            contentView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
            contentView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
        ])

        OfflineViewController.migrateViewContraints(from: currentRoot, to: contentView)

        view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        offlineBanner.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
        currentRoot.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
    }

    private func unembedControllerView() {
        let v = contentView.subviews[0]
        v.removeFromSuperview()
        view = v
        OfflineViewController.migrateViewContraints(from: contentView, to: v)
    }

    /**
     Replaces any constraints associated with the current root's safe area`UILayoutGuide` or with the actual
     current root view.
     */
    private static func migrateViewContraints(from currentRoot: UIView, to newRoot: UIView) {
        for ct in currentRoot.constraints {
            var firstItem: Any? = ct.firstItem
            var secondItem: Any? = ct.secondItem

            if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                if firstItem as? UILayoutGuide == currentRoot.safeAreaLayoutGuide {
                    debugPrint("Migrating firstItem is currentLayoutGuide")
                    firstItem = newRoot.safeAreaLayoutGuide
                }

                if secondItem as? UILayoutGuide == currentRoot.safeAreaLayoutGuide {
                    debugPrint("Migrating secondItem is currentLayoutGuide")
                    secondItem = newRoot.safeAreaLayoutGuide
                }
            }

            if firstItem as? UIView == currentRoot {
                debugPrint("Migrating firstItem is currentRoot")
                firstItem = newRoot
            }

            if secondItem as? UIView == currentRoot {
                debugPrint("Migrating secondItem is currentRoot")
                secondItem = newRoot
            }

            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([ct])
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                NSLayoutConstraint(item: firstItem as Any,
                                   attribute: ct.firstAttribute,
                                   relatedBy: ct.relation,
                                   toItem: secondItem,
                                   attribute: ct.secondAttribute,
                                   multiplier: ct.multiplier,
                                   constant: ct.constant)
            ])
        }
    }
}
```

In this specific view the green buttons does get events it's a button that I create programmatically:

[image: Embed Working]

And here's the view that does not respond to events, a table view with a button:

[image: Embed not working]

Comment: You can disable `userInteraction` on any view that you don't like.

Comment: I don't want to disable it, I want to enable it for the embedded views; they embedded view has interaction enabled by default

Answer (score 0):

I've figured what the issue was; I was missing constraints between `contentView` (the new root view) and the original `self.view`. The constraints essentially made the original `currentRoot` view take the full space of `contentView`:

```swift
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  currentRoot.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 0),
  currentRoot.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
  currentRoot.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0),
  currentRoot.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
])
```